# Core data - can't set nil to an optional relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8

I configured the following core data class:

```
class Project: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var lastUpdateTime: NSDate
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var prevProejct: Project
}
```

A project in this data model can have a previous project. I configured the relationship to be 'optional'. However, the field in the class is not configured as optional - i can't set nil to prevProject.

so how can i set the relationship to nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two thoughts on this:

```
@NSManaged var prevProejct: Project?
```

or:

```
prevProejct = NSNull()
```